# get the hidden field value when link is clicked which is in same cell

Tags: jquery

I am using asp.net data list and i have to find the hidden field value  when anchor of that cell is clicked.

I tried to get the value using `parent()`, `closest()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.document').ready(function () {
            $('.addtocompare').bind('click', function () {

                 var hdnProductId = $(this).parent().find('.hdnProductId  input[type=hidden]').val();
                                alert(hdnProductId);



                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

[JSFIDDLE CAN be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/xGzdG/1/)

Comment: `$('.document')` should be `$(document)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.parents()`

```
 var hdnProductId = $(this).parents().find('.hdnProductId  input[type=hidden]').val();
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xGzdG/3/)

Comment: you used                 var hdnProductId = $(this).parents().find('.hdnProductId  input[type=hidden]:first').val(); in jsfidlle but in aswer i think you miss the First . am i rt ?

Comment: Oh, that was just a test, `:first` is not needed

Comment: difference between parent() and parents() ?

Comment: `parent()` goes only up one level, `parents()` goes up multiple levels

Comment: and using `parents()` without selector will try to find in each parent level. so please use a selector like in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$(this).children('input[type=hidden]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

parent() gives you one level parent...since your hidden inout is inside `<td>` use parents(".tdClass") and you code inside find is not correct

try this

```
var hdnProductId = $(this).parents(".tdClass").find('.hdnProductId  input[type=hidden]').val();
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/xGzdG/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I updated your jsfiddle please check

Note the change in

```
var hdnProductId = $(this).parents().find(".hdnProductId  input[type=hidden]").val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xGzdG/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var hdnProductId = $(this).parents('.CollectionLeftbottom').siblings(".CollectionLeftTop").find('.hdnProductId  input[type=hidden]').val();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xGzdG/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way :

```
var hdnProductId = $(this).closest('td')
                          .find('.hdnProductId  input[type=hidden]').val();
```

Just get to the `.closest()` td of the clicked item and `.find()` the `input[type=hidden]` in that `<td>`.

and plz note:

this is invalid:

```
$('.document')
```

change to this:

```
$(document)
```

#### [Find in FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xGzdG/10/)